Pydrake URDF to SDF parsing failure - name nesting
| drake 1.27.0 | python 3.8 | OS: ubuntu 22.04 | pycharm | ROS 2 Humble |
I'm trying to simulate use of a UR10e with the robotiq 85 gripper for simple pick and place tasks.
I'm using these models - urdfs that are combined using sdf - then parsing them with this code snippet:
    from pydrake.all import (RobotDiagramBuilder, FindResourceOrThrow)

    # Create the diagram builder
    resource = 'description/complete_robot.sdf'
    robot_model_name = 'robot'
    rdb = RobotDiagramBuilder(time_step=1.0e-3)
    rdb.parser().package_map().PopulateFromRosPackagePath()
    rdb.parser().AddModels(FindResourceOrThrow(resource))
    robot_model = rdb.plant().GetModelInstanceByName(robot_model_name)


This code is ran in a ROS 2 python package with the following configuration parameters set for successful identification of the ROS 2 packages referenced by the SDFs:
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH = /home/user/workspaces/my_python_workspace/install/my_python_workspace

The following error is generated and any assistance with adjusting my models or code would be greatly appreciated. Thank you -
Failure at multibody/parsing/detail_sdf_parser.cc:180 in GetRelativeBodyName(): condition 'nested_model_absolute_name.starts_with(required_prefix)' failed. 


I've been able to reproduce the drake parser crash with the models that you linked. A few funny things are going on:

the parser crashed instead of giving an error message; I've filed https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/21413 to track that problem.
the model in gripper.urdf welds itself to the world (see gripper.urdf:116). That is both unlikely to be what you want, and also is the bit that causes the parser to crash.

In order to reproduce the original symptom, I made a few local changes to the model tree:

added a package.xml file at the root (implied by the package uris in complete_robot.sdf).
$ ln -s description descriptions to get the uri spellings to work.

Moving forward, you will also need to convert the .dae mesh files to a format supported by Drake. See https://drake.mit.edu/doxygen_cxx/group__geometry__file__formats.html for supported formats.

More discussion of Drake and .dae format files is here: https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/19109
